# How to simulate a transaction failure?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, transactions, codeigniter-2

I am utilising transactions for some MySQL queries where I am doing multiple inserts across a few tables.

After the transaction has been committed, I am checking the status, throwing an error/exception if it failed.

However, I am struggling to test the case where it fails.

I tried garbling up a column name, but that threw a PHP error instead.

Under what circumstances does a transaction fail, so I can attempt to recreate my own failures for testing purposes?

Comment: Database constraint violations is the easiest to simulate,

Comment: Vote to close for lack of [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or too broad. Supply your code, we can help.

Comment: @MarkBaker I did try that, putting a string into an INT column, but it didn't throw an error :/

Comment: @Drew I'm only asking how to simulate a transaction failure in PHP. Thats the extent of the question I'm afraid!

Comment: then what is your feedback on the Answer below. If you have any, let that user know. Otherwise, we need to see your code, your try catch, something, to see where to wedge it in

Comment: When I'm talking about constraint violations, I mean something like a duplicate key error, or a foreign key entry doesn't exist

Answer (score 1):

try to throw an exception inside your sql script using SIGNAL key word. for exmple:

```
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Custom error';
```

Comment: So I put this inside the transaction, and it spits out a DB Error message, stopping the code going any further and therefore doesn't hit my check on the transaction status :/

Comment: that is exactly how transaction supposed to work. it either hits commit or it rolls back. or maybe i misunderstood what you are trying to simulate

Comment: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/transactions.html read under "Manage Errors". I was hoping to throw my own exception if the status is returned as false, but as stated, this SQLSTATE error stops the code going any further (which yes, seems correct to me too, but then how would you ever hit the status check?)

Comment: you can try to use handlers for the signal and it supposed to give you what you want, although i'm not familiar with how this mechanism works with both mySql and php (i usually work in .net). hope it helped somehow