# Ensure MySQL transaction fails on COMMIT

Tags: mysql, testing, transactions

I want to test a script what it does when MySQL transaction fails. So I want to simulate transaction failure on `COMMIT`.

Image the script opens a transaction, makes some queries, and then commits the transaction. I want to implant some extra query to the transaction, to ensure the transaction will fail on `COMMIT`. So I can test how the script recovers from the transation failure.

I don't want to use explicit `ROLLBACK`. I want to simulate some real-life case when a commit fails. The exact DB structure is unimportant. It may adapt to the solution.

**Edit**: I need the transaction to fail on `COMMIT`, not on some prior query. Therefore answers that rollback prior to `COMMIT` are not what I want. Such as this one: [How to simulate a transaction failure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34314973/how-to-simulate-a-transaction-failure)

**My unsuccessful attempts:**

- Inserting a row with invalid PK or FK fails immediately with insert. Temporarily disabling FK checks with `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0` won't help as they won't be rechecked on `COMMIT`. If it was psql, defferable constraints would help. But not in mysql.
- Opening two parallel transactions and inserting a row with the same PK (or any column with unique constaint) in both transactions locks the later transaction on insert and waits for the former transaction. So the transaction rolls back on insert not on commit.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960189/can-a-commit-statement-in-sql-ever-fail-how This might help , I like the torching your hard drive idea

Comment: @P.Salmon thanks for the link. I seen those answers, but all of them are too theoretical. And approaches with constaints and timeouts seem not work in MySQL. I'm starting to be curious if `COMMIT` can actually fail at all in MySQL.

Comment: So far I managed `COMMIT` to fail only if I killed mysql server before the `COMMIT`. But that's not very convenient for automated tests :-/

Answer (score 0):

So I believe you can try the following

1. Two phase commit : Use two database ( First and second) and make
   use of two phase commit. When the commit statement is supposed to be
   executed you can shutdown the second db. This way your commit
   operation will fail and transaction will rollback.
2. You executed several inserts and before your commit your database server dies. A transaction may fail if it doesn't receive commit .

Hopefully it helps!